# If I’m a dual-citizen working for an American company while living in France, where do I pay taxes?

Tags: taxes, us-citizens, eu-citizens

Planning a move soon and I am trying to figure out the minutiae. Technically I’m a citizen of another Schengen country, not France. I believe I read that the US will count a certain level of income tax paid to a foreign country against your taxes owed to them, as it is intended to prevent offshore tax sheltering, not to double-tax expats, but I’m not sure of the specifics, and I think that was for income earned in that other country anyway. For income (technically) earned in the US, shouldn’t I continue paying American income tax, and just pay French property and sales taxes?

Comment: If you're living in France and performing the work in France you are earning the income in France, even if the source of the income is in another country.

Comment: @phoog that sounds too simplistic. I doubt the US gov. agrees with that.

Comment: @TomasBy The US government doesn't need to agree and even if it would not, France would still expects the OP to fulfill their tax obligations and has every mean to enforce that while they live there.

Comment: @Relaxed sure, but that would not mean not paying US taxes (I assume).